# perl base64 encode with url safe characters

Tags: perl, base64

In a perl script I am using base64 to encode a string , but I want the output to be URL safe
Base64 includes chars like / or + which get converted in an URL

How can I avoid this ?

Comment: Ok base32 works fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lucky for you, "GAAS" has already done it for you.  The module is called [MIME::Base64](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Base64) and if you see about half way down the POD page, the module includes two functions;

`encode_base64url( $bytes )` and

`decode_base64url( $str )`

which *"Encode and decode according to the base64 scheme for "URL applications". This is a variant of the base64 encoding which does not use padding, does not break the string into multiple lines and use the characters "-" and "_" instead of "+" and "/" to avoid using reserved URL characters."*

These functions are not exported by default - which means you need to ask for them as you use the module.  eg:

```
use MIME::Base64 qw(encode_base64url decode_base64url);
my $str = "Hello World";
my $b64_url = encode_base64url($str);
print $b64_url, "\n";
print "Original string: ", decode_base64url($b64_url);
exit 0;
```

Comment: MIME::Base64::URLSafe; has these functions. Not MIME::Base64

Comment: @Ram No, in MIME::Base64::URLSafe they're called urlsafe_b64encode and urlsafe_b64decode. encode_base64url and decode_base64url are in MIME::Base64; look at the source of you're skeptical.

Comment: @Ram By the way, they were added to MIME::Base64 in v3.11 (released in November, 2010), just in case you're running an old version.